# Authentication REST using Services

Tags: services, 8, users

I'm make an Rest module, when I start config, I found this problem, I dont know what I'm missing.

```
How to enable authentication ??

**Authentication**
No authentication modules are enabled, all requests will be anonymous.
```

[image: How to enable authentication ??]

> I cannot POST data, using GET still working

```
<result>Access denied for user anonymous</result>
```

[image: I cannot POST data, using GET still working]

Comment: on your first image, goto **edit** tab. you will find authentications options there on bottom of the form.

Comment: Yes, I have checked "OAuth authentication" in Edit tab, but still not working...

Comment: Shameless plug: You might have more luck with my module, oauth2_server (http://drupal.org/project/oauth2_server), due to better docs.